# How to populate /dev with a custom directory with udev

Tags: linux, udev

For using [gadgetfs](http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/) I have to mount the gadgetfs filesystem to the mount point `/dev/gadget`. But because `/dev` is controlled by *udev* a manually created directory gets lost on each reboot. Sure, I could create the directory in some init.d-Skript but a more clean solution would be to configure udev to automatically create this directory. I'm pretty sure this must be possible somehow because there are lots of other directories in there already.

So how can I configure udev to create a `/dev/gadget` directory automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

Create `/etc/udev/rules/99-gadgetfs.rules` with the following content:

```
ACTION=="add", DEVPATH=="/module/gadgetfs" SUBSYSTEM=="module" RUN+="/bin/mkdir /dev/gadget"
ACTION=="remove", DEVPATH=="/module/gadgetfs" SUBSYSTEM=="module" RUN+="/bin/rmdir /dev/gadget"
```

Restart udev or run this command:

```
udevadm trigger
```

Now when running `modprobe gadgetfs` udev automatically creates the `/dev/gadget` directory which can then be mounted. `rmmod gadgetfs` automatically removes the directory.